# Files not extracted from .jar file when run

Tags: java, ant, build, jar

I have updated my ant build.xml file to include a new file and a new folder.  After creating the .jar I check if they exist in the jar by 'unzip\extract', and they are there.

But when executing the .jar neither the folder or the file gets extracted.

Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 4):

Look into [getResourceAsStream](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/getresourceasstream.html). It'll keep you from having to extract the files from the jar file.  Unless that's your goal.

Answer (score 2):

Your application should be able to use the file directly from within the jar, no need for extracting it. Or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing something specific to extract the jar file?  I ask because normally jar files are not extracted when executing them.

If you run "java -jar myJar.jar" or "java -cp myJar.jar com.example.MyMainClass" the jar files that is referenced will not be extracted.  Java will load your classes and resources directly from the jar file without extracting it.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap your application up using [One-JAR](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net), you can specify an attribute in the Manifest file to extract files that you want  (See the [One-Jar-Expand](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=introduction&file=manifest) manifest attribute).

As a bonus, you will also be able to wrap any dependent libraries along with your code, creating a single distributable jar.